# Force the output query to shows the DB_NAME() data once

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I've got a query that selects all indexes from a table and generate an output text to drop them individually.

I want to put the `DB_NAME()` info in the beginning of command for once, but at this moment the data is showed at every index drop.

I've tried to put a select before, but without success.

Could someone help me? Query and results are below:

**- QUERY**

```
SELECT
  'USE ' + QUOTENAME(db_name()) + ';' + CHAR(13) +
  'GO ' + CHAR(13) +
  'DROP INDEX ' + QUOTENAME(i.name) + ' ON ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.Name) + ';' + CHAR(13) +
  'GO'
FROM
  sys.indexes i
  JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = i.object_id
  JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE
  t.Name = 'Queue';
```

**- Results that I get (example)**

```
USE [master];
GO 
DROP INDEX [PK_Queue] ON [dbo].[Queue];
GO
USE [master];
GO 
DROP INDEX [I_001] ON [dbo].[Queue];
GO
USE [master];
GO 
DROP INDEX [I_002] ON [dbo].[Queue];
GO
```

**- Results that I want**

```
USE [master];
GO 
DROP INDEX [PK_Queue] ON [dbo].[Queue];
GO
DROP INDEX [I_001] ON [dbo].[Queue];
GO
DROP INDEX [I_002] ON [dbo].[Queue];
GO
```

Comment: Why are you doing it this way? You can generate scripts directly using SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: use `row_number()`

Comment: @shree.pat18 Well Im recreating some indexes on specific tables on my envinroment. Ive got the new create indexes queries. I was trying to find out a way to drop them faster cause theres ~300 dbs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just initialize a variable with the `USE` command, and then append the `DROP INDEX` commands using string concatenation. This is easier in SQL Server 2017 (`STRING_AGG()`), but you didn't tell us what version you use, so...

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'USE ' + QUOTENAME(db_name()) + ';';

SELECT @sql += char(13) + N'GO' + char(13) + N'DROP INDEX ' 
  + QUOTENAME(i.name) + ' ON ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) 
  + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + ';' + CHAR(13)
FROM
  sys.indexes i
  JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = i.object_id
  JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE
  t.Name = 'Queue' AND i.name IS NOT NULL;
  
 PRINT @sql;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a2bc4fcd89696e10a088528877fff408)

Comment: Thanks! Btw sorry to not mention, Im using MSSQL 19.

Comment: @carloshnrq Here's a [`STRING_AGG()` equivalent](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=091a12f14ff32d21f09569e29081250e).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Txt
from
(
    SELECT
      1 as Seq,
      'USE ' + QUOTENAME(db_name()) + ';' + CHAR(13) +
      'GO ' + CHAR(13) as Txt
    union all
    SELECT
       2 as Seq,
      'DROP INDEX ' + QUOTENAME(i.name) + ' ON ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.Name) + ';' + CHAR(13) +
      'GO'
    FROM
      sys.indexes i
      JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = i.object_id
      JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
    WHERE
      t.Name = 'Queue'
) S1
order by Seq
```

But, why bother? You can script almost everything in SQL Server Management Studio as @shreepat18 said!